# Print on Ubuntu via Windows 7 printer share without additional printer drivers

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, printer, samba

i got a problem:

i got a *Shinko CHC-S2145* printer and have to print from *Ubuntu 12.04 (x86)* - i need some special features that are only aviable with a linux machine. I installed VirtualBox and created a VM with *Win7 Pro (x86)*.

I've installed the shinko drivers on windows - mounted the printer (USB2.0) on the VM and i could print.

Now I need to print from Ubuntu through Windows. I can add the printer as samba share (host-only adapter) but it needs the drivers (i dont have..).

I've tried lots of other drivers, i tried to install driver software with wine - but it didn't worked at all.

So is there a way to add the print from the VM to Ubuntu without additional drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

We've tried to add a driver from an similar printer, edited many configs but this printer driver seems to be bigger.

So our special feature (controlling hardware by sending data on usb->rs232) that had problems with windows just got moved to an ubuntu 12.04 VirtualBox with guest-additions and share usb-device. The Host is windows with the official driver.

Not the prettiest way, but till now it works pretty well.